# How does the "Views" count inside modern pages exactly works

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, modern-pages

I did not find any relevant info of how the "Views" section inside modern pages exactly work?

[image]

is it based on unique users visits? or per request visit? also how long will it take doe the Views counter to increment, is it based on the search service?

**EDIT** Also when i accessed the page from the `Site Pages` list, and i select the modern page, i got a popup box named `File Statistics` as follow:-

[image]

where it showed that i have 26 viewers with 353 views.

Also using the search api `https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:News*+path:https://***.sharepoint.com/'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers'` (as described in @vinit kumar reply) i got a property named `ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers` which showed the number = 99.

**so in my case what do these numbers really represents "26" & "353" & "99" ?**

Comment: it is based on per request visit not unique visitor as per my understanding. and Yes Views is based on Search service and counter will get Increment once Search Service crawled again and refresh the content

Answer (score 2):

It is based on per page request by users not unique users visit and Yes Views is based on Search service and counter will get Increment once Search Service crawled again and refresh the content.If you still want to get the Page Unique Views then you can get using Search API as below

```
_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:News*+path:YourSiteURL/'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers'
```

`ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers` - it's property to get Unique Page visitor

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think there is something missing as when i run your query i got an error that `the query string "selectProperties" is missing or invalid.`. so i chnage it to `select`, but on the returned result i did not find any xml property named `ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers `!!

Comment: Above code is working code currently. May be you can share your complete search api url except your site url. Wanted to see what's the issue if it all it has.

Comment: here is my complete url `https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:News*+path:https://***.sharepoint.com/'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers` where i got `The query string "selectProperties" is missing or invalid.`

Comment: Hi John, i think you have missed ' at the end of the URL.  https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:News*+path:https://***.sharepoint.com/'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers'

Comment: ok i added the `'` and i now i got the `ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers` for the modern page = `99` in my case. So i thought i have `99` unique users have actually accessed the modern page. but today when i select my modern page inside the `site pages` list, i got a popup box named `File Statistic` and it showed that i have 26 viewers + 345 views (i edit my original question with a picture of this box).. now 26 viewers is more realistic in my case.. so i am not sure what is the differences between `ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers` and the number of viewers i got inside my `file statistic` popup ??

Comment: sorry John, now i too got confused.may be this blog help you to understand about vistitors and viewers difference. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188202/what-is-the-difference-between-visitors-and-viewers-in-sharepoint-2013    . I feel UniqueViewer means by any means if you have access the page.if news page properties might be it get accessed in Home page News webpart.but Views is something you view the page exactly by loading the content in Browser

Comment: i think the link you provided talks about Visitors and Viewer from  a permission level perspective,,,