# Itemanalytics api throws error - the expression is not valid

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, page-view

I am working in SharePoint Online. I want to get modern page view count. I am searching for this on google and I fount [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2808) link. In that if you scroll in the end of page, you will see that says Microsoft is building Itemanalytics api. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-beta) is link for reference.

I tried to test this in graph explorer. Below is my URL for item analytics:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/%7Bef9075ed-0978-441c-9c32-c0cc109e7604%7D/lists/%7Be5420cdd-4787-4a5e-8fb4-16356edc4d07%7D/items/%7Bbf29bb29-95f4-4edb-b29f-cfdf4d57f76b%7D/analytics
```

The issue is when I run this in graph explorer, it throws me error that

```
The expression \"sites('tenantname.sharepoint.com')/sites/{ef9075ed-0978-441c-9c32-c0cc109e7604}/lists('{e5420cdd-4787-4a5e-8fb4-16356edc4d07}')/items/{bf29bb29-95f4-4edb-b29f-cfdf4d57f76b}/analytics\" is not valid."
```

Anyone that have work on this, can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have checked the search API way that is explained [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247064/how-does-the-views-count-inside-modern-pages-exactly-works). But it is not working on my end. It is giving null value. Do anyone has any other option to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how to get Modern page count. But your graph API Request URL is not correct. It should be as below

For Lists

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com,b152c541-8d93-4403-9656-77c5940b67d3,20806aeb-365f-4708-8c5c-416b998276f7/lists/43838d29-e559-41eb-809d-7599f778adf0/items/2
```

For Library

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com,b152c541-8d93-4403-9656-77c5940b67d3,20806aeb-365f-4708-8c5c-416b998276f7/drives/b!QcVSsZONA0SWVnfFlAtn0-tqgCBfNghHjFxBa5mCdvcf3evJwzMDQJJ2GdbJlRWm/items/5
```

If you need help to get site id and drive id then you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240319/access-files-of-document-library-site-through-microsoft-graph-api#answer-45763760)

Comment: Hi. I am able to get list of SharePoint list using your first API. But I am facing issue while getting site pages library. Its neither in list nor in library result. So I am not able to get its pages.

Comment: For page you have to use Library url. Because pages it's self library

Comment: Site Pages is library but there are no Site pages drive. So how to get drive id for Site pages

Comment: Hi @lovethakker, you can refer https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/sitepage-list.md link to get site pages. Make sure you give proper permission to access

Comment: I am checking with tenant admin user. I am not sure how more permission I can give.

Comment: MS graph api is doesn't work as REST API. There are two type of permission `Delegated` and `Application`. So `delegate` permission work based on current user permission but `Application` permission work regardless of current login.

Comment: it shows me site pages details but not providing detail of no of view and not showing site pages drive id.

Comment: as I mention I am not sure about no of view. You can get drive id by following url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com,b152c541-8d93-4403-9656-77c5940b67d3,20806aeb-365f-4708-8c5c-416b998276f7/drives

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comment, `drives` api do not include pages or site pages. They have developed `pages` api for fetching site pages data. But its neither giving its drive id nor page view counts.